# custom port assign to PgAdmin4 by NGINX configuration in docker container cluster

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, reverse-proxy, pgadmin-4

I am trying to do reverse proxy in my Docker container. I am trying to use PgAdmin4 in port 8080, not 80. For security reasons, I am not using Docker port forwarding. I am trying to use Nginx to reverse proxy pgAdmin's port 80 to 8080. my Nginx code :

```
server {
  listen 8080; 
  location / {
      proxy_pass  http://pgadmin_test:80/;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_set_header Host $host
  }
}
```

This code is not working.

But if I use port 80 in Nginx, it works properly

```
server {
   listen 80; 
   location / {
      proxy_pass  http://pgadmin_test:80/;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_set_header Host $host
   }
}
```

The git hub link is: https://github.com/subhadipsjsc/docker_nginx_pgadmin

Comment: What you want is your Nginx to listen on 80, then, proxying requests to port 8080. So it's obvious that Nginx listening on 8080 doesn't do that. Your second configuration is right and you're not exposing your pgAdmin anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

nginx_test:
    build: ./nginx
    container_name: nginx_test
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"

pgadmin_test:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    restart: always
    depends_on:
    - postgres_test
    ports:
    - 80:80

server {
    listen 3000;

```
location / {
    proxy_pass  http://pgadmin_test:80/;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Here is the official documentation: https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/latest/container_deployment.html#http-via-nginx

For me this was helpful because I wanted pgadmin mounted in a subroute /pgadmin